# Copy a file to a folder in a docker container in JAVA

Tags: docker

1. I have a docker container running SQL Server.
2. I would like to copy a mdf file from my local machine to a folder within a running container. How do i do that?
3. i can copy some file Using Jsch library to the host but how do i do that within a running container in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `docker cp`

```
docker cp foo.txt <container-id>:/foo.txt
```